# How to Reveal ViewController Storyboard Elements from a NavBarController inside of a TabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller

So I have a CustomTabBarController that is created programmatically (not through storyboard). Inside of the viewDidLoad(), I create a ProfileNavController with the view controller being ProfileViewController(), also programmatically:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ProfileNavController <- ProfileController
    let profileController = ProfileViewController()
    let profileNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profileController)
    let modifiedProfileNavController = UITabBarItem(title: "Profile", image: UIImage(named: ""), selectedImage: UIImage(named: ""))
    profileNavController.tabBarItem = modifiedProfileNavController

    // Tab-bar selector (ignore the "recentMessagesNavController", StackOverflow)
    viewControllers = [recentMessagesNavController, createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("Groups", imageName: ""), createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("Submit", imageName: ""), createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("Search", imageName: ""), profileNavController]
}
```

I then created a Profile.storyboard and assigned the View Controller's class to ProfileViewController in the identity inspector (in the right hand column). Inside of the storyboard view controller I put a label titled "Hello World".

The problem is that whenever I run the program and click on the Profile tab, the label (along with everything else from the storyboard) does not show up. How do I get them to show?

**ProfileViewController.swift for reference:**

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        navigationItem.title = "Profile"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to intialise `ProfileViewController` with its storyboard reference

```
let profileController = ProfileViewController()
```

change it to

```
let profileController = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
```

Comment: This partially worked, although I had to modify it to: `let profileController = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profileViewController") as UIViewController` because I'm assuming the viewcontroller had no initial entry point in the storyboard. Thanks!